# Java copy constructor not working

Tags: java, deep-copy

I have read many posts about copy constructors but I just can't seem to get it to work.  I call the copy constructor but the object still modifies the original:

```
public class Board {
    private Square[][] board = getEmptyBoard();

    public Board() {    
    }

    public Board(Board originalBoard) {
        Square[][] matrix = new Square[6][6];
        for(int row = 0; row <= 5; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col <= 5; col++) {
                matrix[row][col] = originalBoard.getSquare(row, col);
            }
        }
        this.board = matrix;
    }
    [...]
}
```

The class models a six-by-six board of type `Square`.  A `Square` is an object that can hold one or more objects of type `Piece`.

How can I take my original board and make and exact copy of it so that I can add and remove the `Piece`s from the `Square`s without touching the original `Board` objects?

Comment: Apparently your `getSquare` method returns `Square` instance from `originalBoard`. You should create a copy for each `Square` instance as well.

Comment: As question's tag suggests you need to do deep copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your deep copy isn't going deep enough.  You've created your own 2D `Square` array, but the array is referring to the same `Square` objects as `originalBoard` is.

You'll need to make a copy of the `Square` object that you're getting from `originalBoard`.  Depending on what the `Square` object holds, you'll need to make copies of its attributes (e.g. `Piece`) in a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Object`s (`Square`) instead of primitives, by associating `matrix[row][col] = originalBoard.getSquare(row, col);` you are getting the reference of your object, any modification will change both references.

If you want to copy the exact state and modify then you should implements Cloneable at your Square class and call the `clone()` when associating to the copy array.